# Bulk Data insert from CSV to SQL Server using Console Application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, csv

Need to insert a local .csv file, around 6MB, 130k rows. I need to open the file in a c# program, insert each row, each row having special considerations (quotes around each field).

Wondering the best way to go about this, as I've never written a c# app the inserts to a db. I have done the below directly on the DB, but now need to do this within a c# app.

```
BULK
INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

The sample data within the .csv file is below, and I'm a little lost on how to strip the quotes out when inserting to the DB from c#. Do I need to specify the column names in c#, or can I insert something similar to the T-SQL query?

```
Copyright (c) 2011 MaxMind Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
"beginIp","endIp","beginIpNum","endIpNum","countryCode","countryName"
"1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","16777216","16777471","AU","Australia"
"1.0.1.0","1.0.3.255","16777472","16778239","CN","China"
"1.0.4.0","1.0.7.255","16778240","16779263","AU","Australia"
```

And for those 1st 2 lines I know I need to do 2 reader.ReadLine();'s to ignore them. Any help for a c# newb is welcome! The fields are exactly the same throughout the .csv file, so that would not be a problem. Just don't know if theres an easy way to insert data from a large csv to SQL via c#. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

What I'm now using, that beautifully gets .csv fields, even within quotes, given TGH's example link. Now just need to insert via SQL connection.

```
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\StreamReadTest.csv"))
        {
            parser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
            parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

            // Skip over header line.
            parser.ReadLine();
            // Skip field descriptions line.
            parser.ReadLine();

            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

                foreach (var value in fields)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(value);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't develop, use OSQL utility.

Comment: @Darek I'd never heard of OSQL, but [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806.aspx) says "This feature will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use the feature. Use sqlcmd instead. For more information, see [sqlcmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) Utility."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

You can create a SqlCommand and run the raw sql string you defined above. Alternatively you could wrap the sql in a stored proc and call it from .Net using Ado.net.

Another approach is to parse the file and save the individual rows through .Net (ado.Net or an ORM like Entity Framework)
I would consider looking into the following library (.net built in csv parser) for parsing the file:
http://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/built-in-net-csv-parser/

Comment: Thanks for your help! That link knocked out two things I needed, how to get fields easily within quotes, and skip the two first lines of my .csv file. Any guidance on inserting this to a MSSQL DB? The table is already made, just containing the same fields: "beginIp","endIp","beginIpNum","endIpNum","countryCode","countryName" I have not connected and inserted to a c# db using parsed .csv data so any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: There are a few different ways. One is Entity framework (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application), but you can also consider Ado.Net.